# Composite attribute within f:facets tag of another composite component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, composite-component

Assuming I do have a composite attribute `elementId`.

```
 <composite:implementation>
    ...
    <x:popupTooltip>
       ...
       <f:facet name="tooltip">
          <rich:message for="#{cc.attrs.elementId}" />
          ...
```

`#{cc.attrs.elementId}` is always empty within the `<f:facet .../>` tag. However, adding the parameter ouside of `<f:facet ... />`, it will be rendered correctly.

How can I use a composite attribute or a `<ui:param ... />` value (I tried this too) within a `<f:facet .../>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EL is always evaluated in the context of the current component. The `#{cc}` in your `<rich:message>` is actually referring to `<x:popupTooltip>`. Your best bet is passing that attribute through to the `<x:popupTooltip>` so that it's also aware of that attribute.

```
<x:popupTooltip elementId="#{cc.attrs.elementId}">
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I did as an workaround. :-) But this has lead into duplicated code since the `elementId` was used only for a very specific code.

Comment: You're welcome. That said, I'm a bit afraid that you're simply going overboard as to using composites for the particular purpose. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen/6822269#6822269